Is Starship monocoqué?
Does Starship have any internal bracing to support it? Or is it a "balloon tank" relying on tank pressure to stand?

There is a lot of internal bracing which you can see evidence of in close-up shots with all of the rows of rivets. And a few rare interior photos have been released also showing bracing. Both stages can sit upright on the stand or launch mount unpressurized. From what I remember they used to slightly pressurize the stages when moving them to and from the launch site to better handle any bending loads, but newer vehicles have had extra reinforcement so they don't have to do that anymore.,
